# How to access "key" in combine.perKey in beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In [How to create custom Combine.PerKey in beam sdk 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198554/how-to-create-custom-combine-perkey-in-beam-sdk-2-0/45199743#45199743), I asked and got a correct answer on how to create a custom Combine.PerKey in the new beam sdk 2.0. However, I now need to create a custom combinePerKey such that within my custom CombinePerKey logic, I need to be able to access the contents of the key. This was easily possible in dataflow 1.x, but in the new beam sdk 2.0, I'm unsure how to do so. Any little code snippet/example would be extremely useful.

EDIT #1 (per Ben Chambers's request)

The real use case is hard to explain, but I'm going to try:

We have a 3d space composed of millions of little hills. We try to determine the apex of these millions of hills as follows: we create billions of "rectangular probes" for the whole 3d space, and then we ask each of these billions of probes to "move" in a greedy way to the apex. Once it hits the apex, it stops. The probe then returns the apex and itself. The apex is the KEY for which we'll do a custom combine by key.

Now, the custom combine function is going to finally return a final object (called a feature) which is derived from all the probes that reach the same apex (ie the same key). When generating this "feature" object, we need to know infomration about the final apex/key (ie the top of the hill). Hence, I need this key info.

One way to solve this is using a group by key, but that was slow (at least in df 1.x); we got it to be fast (in df 1.x) using a custom combine fn. So, we'd like the key. That said, groupbykey works in beam skd 2.0.

Alternatively, we could stick the "apex" information into the "probe" objects itself, but this means that each of our billions of probe objects now needs to be tripled in size just to hold this apex information (and this apex information repeats itself, since there are only say 1 million apexes but 1 billion probes, so this intuitively feels highly inefficient.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case? We removed the ability for `CombineFn`s to access the key because it was typically misused. Most cases we've seen can be handled by either pre-processing the input or post-processing the output with a DoFn that is accesses the key.

Comment: @BenChambers I added use-case above under "EDIT #1"

Comment: @BenChambers just bumping this one up...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the CombineFn to compute the entire result, could you instead have the ComibneFn compute some partial result based only on information about the probes? Then your `Combine.perKey(...)` returns a `PCollection<KV<Apex, InfoAboutProbes>>` and you can use a `ParDo` to combine the information about the apex with the summary information about the probes. This allows you to use the `CombineFn` for efficiently combining information about many probes, while using a `ParDo` to access the key.